How can I play content from my iPhone 15 to my ipad 9 on ios 17?
I try to share content from iphone 15 to ipad 9 over airplay (both iOS 17.5.1). But the ipad don't appear in the control screen from iphone. But sharing to my macbook is not problem. How can fix this?
Answers on base of very old ios i.e. Is it possible to airplay content from iPhone to another iPhone or iPad? (from 2016!!!) don't solve the problem. Apple has changed airplay significantly in the last 8 years!

https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/253734/162601 DoN't answer the question!
The answer based on technical level of ios from 2016! It's now deprecated! Please rollback the answer close!!!

https://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/mac/ still seems to be available. What do I miss here?
